# How to convert datetime to date in mvc 4 reports

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I  am working With mvc 4 in my table there is one field which is created_date

i have to display only date in my reports 
at that time in my reports display date and time

Comment: What is the type of the field created_date? String? Or DateTime?

Answer (score 0):

To return only the date part of a `DateTime`, use the property `myDateTimeInstance.Date`. That will set the hours, minutes and seconds to 0.

If you want a string, just use: `myDateTimeInstance.ToShortDateString()`.

Comment: @user3222846 Not sure, really - Wherever you map the date before creating the report. There's really not enough info in your question to provide a detailed answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
created_date.ToString("d")
```

Or

```
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", created_date);
```